# Error Compiling Synapse Project

Tags: ubuntu, vala

I am trying to compile the synapse project from [this code](https://code.launchpad.net/~synapse-core/synapse-project/trunk) but I am having some difficulty doing so. I get the following error after running `./configure && make`:

```
utils.vala:336.29-336.41: error: The name `FileAttribute' does not exist in the context of `Synapse.Utils.FileInfo'
                            FileAttribute.STANDARD_DISPLAY_NAME,
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
utils.vala:337.29-337.41: error: The name `FileAttribute' does not exist in the context of `Synapse.Utils.FileInfo'
                            FileAttribute.STANDARD_ICON,
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
utils.vala:338.29-338.41: error: The name `FileAttribute' does not exist in the context of `Synapse.Utils.FileInfo'
                            FileAttribute.STANDARD_FAST_CONTENT_TYPE,
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
utils.vala:339.29-339.41: error: The name `FileAttribute' does not exist in the context of `Synapse.Utils.FileInfo'
                            FileAttribute.THUMBNAIL_PATH,
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I have no experience with Vala so I don't know what the issue could be. I have installed all the dependencies necessary but it seems to be a problem with the vala compiler.

I installed valac 0.14 as specified in their README.

The reason I am trying to compile synapse from source is that there is an annoying bug in synapse right now which causes your shortcut settings to be reset everytime synapse is closed. Unfortunately synapse does not seems to be maintained anymore and I wish to fix it for myself.... as soon as I can compile it!

I am trying to compile this on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Comment: `GLib.FileAttribute` is part of gio-2.0 as you can see here: http://valadoc.org/#!api=gio-2.0/GLib.FileAttribute

Comment: According to synaptic I seem to have the necessary libraries installed. The rest are bindings for CLI (.NET) and Haskell which obviously do not apply to Vala. 

[This page](http://valadoc.org/#!wiki=gio-2.0/index) suggests installing it for Vala using PackageKit but it seems to be down. Is Vala pretty much not used anymore?

Comment: On the contrary: Many current GNOME applications are written in Vala. libglib2.0-dev contains gio-2.0, you should already have this package installed (sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev).

Comment: You should report that error to the valadoc.org maintainer http://valadoc.org/#!wiki=about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `GLib.FileAttribute` namespace didn't exist until [2012-01-12](https://git.gnome.org/browse/vala/commit/?id=132d0a4eae887462d1f8fc885c3d9a66ef383d78).  The first stable version with that commit was valac-0.16.  That said, any version of valac newer than 0.16 should work, including [the default version](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/valac) (which is currently 0.22.1).

Comment: I thought OP had installed valac-0.24, now it makes sense. valac-0.14 is very old.

Comment: I am indeed usign valac-0.14 because the README file in project says the following: `This version of Synapse officially supports only Vala 0.14.`. Will try using 0.16 and report back to you with results.

Comment: Using valac-0.16 or higher works. Filed a bug report to the synapse devs and also fixed it myself in a mirror repo. Thanks!